# Iterate through array one click at a time

Tags: javascript

I'm going over basic JavaScript and build a tiny hotels app to practice.  I ran into a problem when trying to iterate through an array one click at a time.  Meaning.... that I wanted to make on mouseclick and iterate through one index in the array.  Essentially being able to display one hotel's info at a time with the click of a mouse.  I wrote some code that actually worked but I think there must be a better way to do this.  I'm wondering what is a more efficient way of doing this.

My HTML

```
<body>

  <div class="background">
    <div class="cover">
      <div class="space"></div>
      <div id="button">
        <h1>Check Availablility</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="name-div">
        <h1 id="name"></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="rooms-div">
        <h1 id="rooms"></h1>
        <h3>rooms left</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

My JavaScript

```
function Hotel(name, rooms, booked) {
  this.name = name;
  this.rooms = rooms;
  this.booked = booked;

  this.checkAvailability = function () {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  }

};

var quay = new Hotel('Quay', 40, 25);
var park = new Hotel('Park', 100, 33);
var dream = new Hotel('Dream', 77, 40);
var cod = new Hotel('Cod', 49, 21);
var hotels = [quay, park, dream, cod];

const button = document.getElementById('button');
const name = document.getElementById('name');
const rooms = document.getElementById('rooms');

var i = 0;
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (i < hotels.length) {
      name.textContent = hotels[i].name;
      rooms.textContent = hotels[i].checkAvailability();
      i++;
      if (i == hotels.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
    }
});
```

Any insight would be awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: Unless it's broken, it should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok.  Didn't there was such a thing.

Comment: In any case, it seems fine. Not sure what you mean by more efficient. For a little vanilla js thing it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I probably use your approach most of times, but it's good to know that since ECMAScript 2015 we could use [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) for this kind of situations. A basic example could be:

```
function* idMaker() {
  var index = 0;
  while (index < index+1)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen.next().value); // 3
```

In your implementation could be something   like:

```
function* doSomethingOnClick(length){
        var index = 0;
        while(index < length){
         name.textContent = hotels[index].name;
         rooms.textContent = hotels[index].checkAvailability();
          yield index++;
          if(index==length){
            index = 0;  
          }
        }

      }

var gen = doSomethingOnClick(hotels.length);

      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        gen.next();
    })
```

And a full example here https://jsfiddle.net/uh7n329s/9/